# IEEE template: Sections in the appendix

Tags: appendices, ieeetran

I try to make sections in the appendix, but they do not appear?

My code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\section{Testsection1}
Test

\section{Testsection2}
Test

\section{Testsection3}
Test

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I thought there should be some headings? Can this be "fixed"?

Thank you

Comment: This is a desired feature of `IEEEtran` and clearly stated in the manual, see section `XIII` on page 15, right column: `\appendix` disables `\section`

Comment: after `\appendix`˙(which is treated as section)  you can have only `\subsection{...}`. but if you like to have sections, than you should use `\begin{appendices}

\section{Test section1}
Test

\section{Test section2}
Test

\section{Test section3}
Test
\end{appendices}`

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works:)! I will read the manuel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IEEEtran` class disables the `\section` macro after the `\appendix`

See section `XIII` on page `15`, right column:

> \appendix disables \section

So only `\subsection` etc. are available or use the `appendix` package and `\begin{appendices} \section{foo}...\end{appendices}` instead of `\appendix` etc. (as suggested by Zarko)

Comment: what if I want sections after an appendix. FOr instance supplementary materials?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\appendices`

or `\begin{appendices}` and `\end{appendices}`

If you use \appendix it means you only have one appendix so it does not have headings.

> if there is only one Appendix in the article,
> leave the Appendix unnumbered and unnamed as is. (Appendix subheads should also not be enumerated in this
> case.)

From the link https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Editorial-Style-Manual-for-Authors.pdf